# Finding log base when given only a graph

Tags: logarithms

I have the function f(x)=log_bx is shown as a graph and the only two points are (5,1) and it's asking me to find the base of the logarithmic function.

Comment: For what base $b$ does $f(x) = \log_b x$ pass through the point $(5, 1)$? But that might be misleading--what is the other point your graph passes through?

Comment: That is the only point given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exponentiating both sides gives:
$$
\log_b 5 = 1 \Rightarrow \\
b^{\log_b 5} = b^1 \Rightarrow \\
5 = b
$$